# Rails4 model ignores parent_id on 'create' action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Subcategories which belong to Categories. My app saves (build) all my Subcategories under Subcategory with id = 1, even though my code seems to be ok and it is not supposed to do that:

Subcategories controller:

```
    def create
      @category = Category.find_by(params[:id])
      @subcategory = @category.subcategories.build(subcategory_params)
      if @subcategory.save
        flash[:success] = "added subcategory"
        redirect_to admin_categories_url
      else
        render :new
      end
    end

...

    private

      def subcategory_params
        params.require(:subcategory).permit(:name, :category_id)
      end
```

Subcategory.rb

```
class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :products

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :category_id, presence: true
end
```

Form:

```
<h3>Add a subcategory</h3>

<%= form_for [@category, @subcategory] do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name" %>
  <%= f.submit "Add a subcategory" %>
<% end %>
```

router:

```
resources :categories do
    resources :subcategories
  end
```

URL:

Adding a new subcategory to category with id = 3

```
http://localhost:3000/categories/3/subcategories/new
```

Logs:

```
Started POST "/categories/1/subcategories" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-16 16:04:47 +0400
Processing by SubcategoriesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", authenticity_token"=>"74U3VyAN6NqEjhkuHGNHnPda/yzpc+dIcn2xBJ6Zi2A=", "subcategory"=>{"name"=>"A name"}, "commit"=>"Add subcategory", "category_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  WHERE "categories"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "subcategories" ("category_id", "created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["category_id", 1], ["created_at", "2014-04-16 12:04:47.151729"], ["name", "A name"], ["updated_at", "2014-04-16 12:04:47.151729"]]
   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
```

Id is 1

What can be the problem here?

**Update**

When doing

```
@category = Category.find_by(params[:category_id])
```

this error comes up:

```
ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer
LINE 1: SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  WHERE (1) LIMIT 1
```

If doing

```
@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
```

problem presists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `create` action you are picking up the id of the subcategory, not the category.  Change it to:

```
def create
  @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  ...
```

The same change to setting `@category` needs to be made in the `new` method too so that `category_id` comes back as 3 in the params from the view.  Of course this duplication can be also DRYed up using a helper method in the controller.

To see the difference in the id, you can use `rake routes` and you should see something like:

```
new_category_subcategory   GET   /categories/:category_id/subcategories/new   subcategories#new
```

This shows you that it expects the parameter `category_id` for the id of the category.

Comment: getting an error: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer
LINE 1: SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  WHERE (1) LIMIT 1

Comment: Sorry, should have been `find` not `find_by`

Comment: You also need to make the same change to setting `@category` in your `new` model so that `category_id` comes back as 3 in the params from the view.

Comment: No problem :)  Sorry for the couple of errors in my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your parameters it consist `category_id` not `id`

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", authenticity_token"=>"74U3VyAN6NqEjhkuHGNHnPda/yzpc+dIcn2xBJ6Zi2A=", "subcategory"=>{"name"=>"A name"}, "commit"=>"Add subcategory", "category_id"=>"1"}
```

#=>   "category_id"=>"1"

```
   Category.find_by(category_id: params[:category_id])
```

So you need to do

```
 def create
  @category = Category.find_by(category_id: params[:category_id])
  @subcategory = @category.subcategories.build(subcategory_params)
  if @subcategory.save
    flash[:success] = "added subcategory"
    redirect_to admin_categories_url
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: if i do that, i get an error: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer
LINE 1: SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  WHERE (1) LIMIT 1

Comment: `params.require(:subcategory).permit(:name, :category_id)` it should be `params.require(:subcategory).permit(:name)`